# Are there books that teach mathematics in the style of a documentation for any programming language?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request, programming

I am trying to deepen my knowledge in mathematics (calculus, linear algebra, analytical geometry and statistics).
I have a facility with the style as libraries and languages ​​are presented: Use X method to solve Y problem.
Are there books that deal with the themes mentioned in this format instead of focusing on proofs and theoretical rigor?

Comment: One might say that without focus on proofs and rigor, such books are not "real" math books. And even when you are interested more in an "engineer-ish" view of applications, it is always extremely important to know when a method loses applicability due to complexity or loss of precision or whatnot (so again rigor and proofs)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is right, and you will surely run into numeric problems (rounding errors summing up). And I really don't know *any* programming language that buys you free from that.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I don't want to polemicate, and take the following with humor:  we can welcome to the mathematics paradise people who consider, use (and often like) mathematics for their capacity to modelize and solve practical problems, even if they commit the sin not to be interested by proofs (being in general fully confident into the people who have created the results they use)...

Comment: Here is a classical book: "How to solve it ?" by G. Polya who, besides, is a well known mathematician.

Comment: Proofs and rigor are, in my opinion, what gives the mathematics its beauty and, although that may not be important to you, it also gives the mathematics a certain abstracted depth that those who might use the math would require in order to use them properly and reliably.  Without understanding the "whys", you may be tempted, for example, and I am exaggerating for effect, to use the quadratic method solve a cubic equation. Even the highly skilled and expert mathematician is not immune from mistakes, implementing processes not suitable for the conditions. A layman has less background.

Comment: Anyone can punch numbers into a calculator, equations into a computer algebra system, or meticulously follow processes on paper. The art and wisdom is in knowing whether or not the answers you get on the back end hold any meaning and, why or why not. If not, what to do about it and how to avoid it in the future.  A layman will, like so many students, just "go with it", sometimes oblivious to obvious nonsense. Sometimes subtle.  Now, should you rely on your own mathematical prowess, blindly following a procedure without insight, one should hope your life or livelihood werent on the line.